# Cannot install sonata admin on Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony4, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-4.4

I installed symfony 4.4 full, and then tried to install sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle.
Out of the box, this doesn't work. can someone please explain this?

I got the same error using symfony 5.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle ^3.21 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle[3.21.0].
    - Conclusion: remove twig/twig v3.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v3.0.5
    - sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle 3.21.0 requires twig/twig ^1.41 || ^2.10 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v2.12.0, v2.12.1, v2.12.2, v2.12.3, v2.12.4, v2.12.5, v2.13.0, v2.13.1].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.12.0, v3.0.5].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.12.1, v3.0.5].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.12.2, v3.0.5].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.12.3, v3.0.5].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.12.4, v3.0.5].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.12.5, v3.0.5].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.13.0, v3.0.5].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.13.1, v3.0.5].
    - Installation request for twig/twig (locked at v3.0.5, required as ^2.12|^3.0) -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v3.0.5].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use composer require "sonata-project/admin-bundle:^3.56" "twig/twig:^2.10"

Answer (score 1):

You need to install one of the specified version of twig before installing sonata.

Sonata has a dependency on twig.